# Overflow error on Android TV caused by keyboard showing

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am getting the dreaded black and yellow striped bar on my login screen which is stopping users from logging in when the keyboard pops up. I've tried fixing this error on my login screen in the past with no luck. Here is the screenshot.

[image: Android TV]

Here is the offending code:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
   return new Scaffold(
     body: Container (
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
            colors: [Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0), Color.fromRGBO(1,89,99, 1.0)],
            begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            end: Alignment.topRight
        )
    ),
     child: new Column(

      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,


      children:[
                           Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),     
                                    child:Image.asset('lib/img/LBConnect2_white_small_trans.png'),

                                     ), 
                                      new LoginForm(),
                             ]) 

                             ),
     );




   }
```

Login Form class code

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
 createState()
 {
   return new LoginFormState();
   }

} 

class LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> with Validation
{

   final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   String emailAddress = '';
   String passWord = '';
   String token;
   Widget build(context) {
   return  SingleChildScrollView (
       child: Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: Form(
    key: formKey,
    child: Column(
       children: [
            emailField(),
         passwordField(),   
         Container(
         margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child:OutlineButton(
        child: Text('LOGIN'), textColor: Colors.white,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
          onPressed: (){
          if(formKey.currentState.validate()){

           formKey.currentState.save();
           loginUser(emailAddress, passWord, token);

              }
            }
            )
             ),



   Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
       child: OutlineButton(
             child: Text('Create Account'), textColor: Colors.white,
          shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
            onPressed: () { 
              Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => 
    new ProfileStep1()));
             },
        ),
       ),

       ],
    ),      
  )
)
```

);

```
}

Widget emailField()
{
        return TextFormField(
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
         decoration : InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'Email Address',
           labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

         ),

         validator: validateEmail,
         onSaved: (String value){

           emailAddress = value;

         },

   );
```

}

```
  Widget passwordField()
  {
     return TextFormField(
         style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
         obscureText: true,
         decoration : InputDecoration(
           labelText: 'Password',
           labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),

         ),

         validator: validatePassword,
          onSaved: (String value){

            passWord = value;
         },

   );
  }


Future<User> loginUser(String username, String password, String token ) async {
 final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
 String token = await _fcm.getToken();
 //print(token);
  final response =
      await http.post('api/Login',
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
      body: json.encode({'email' : username ,  'password' : password, 'token': token}));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    User _user;
  _user = User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  if(_user.userId.length > 1)
  {
  // Check user group and send them to proper home screen
  if (_user.groupName == 'Member')
   {
  // Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new FirebaseTest()));

   Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new FlutterReduxApp(user: _user)));
   }
   // Caregiver has logged in
   else{

     Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => new LoginChoose(user: _user)));
   }
}

return _user;

  } else {
    // If that call was not successful, throw an error.
    throw Exception('Failed to load user');
  }

}

}
```

This only occurs when the keyboard shows upon clicking on a textfield. As you can see the login button is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your loginForm in a [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) , wich in case of overflow, it allows the user to scroll down

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   child : LoginForm();
)
```

OR

You could "sacrifice" your image height to be smaller when there is less space , for that, use [Flexible](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

```
Column(
    children:[
        Flexible(child:Center(    
        child:Image.asset('lib/img/LBConnect2_white_small_trans.png'),
        )), 
        new LoginForm(),
])
```

There is more options, including using a [OrientationBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/OrientationBuilder-class.html) to be responsive on landscape , and more . Those 2 examples are the 2 i would use